# parallel computation and GPGPU question

Tags: distributed-systems

is there a mean of creating a cluster of machines, that can be seen as an entire system, using perhaps mac OS X or mac os x server, and use parallelism and GPGPU optimisation to compute all the tasks of a system,as a single machine? Kind Regards

Comment: that means, software which is not usually optimised for the purpose

Comment: are you talking about for a general computation task? unfortunately GPU programming currently requires a lot of specialized human attn/ optimization eg via CUDA language. that may never change. so yes it can be done & is done but requires custom programming.

Comment: Of course you can create a cluster of machines.  What would stop you?  Can you explain why you are uncertain or what your specific confusion is, so we can provide a more useful answer?  It's hard to provide a useful explanation, as you haven't given us much to work with about the reason you are asking.  Also, note that questions about specific operating systems (like Mac OS X), as are requests for tools or software products.

Comment: so imagine, that i want to run standard productivity software. as far as i am concerned, for both GPGPU and clustering, you would need to optimize the software for running in such an architecture. my question has to do with the existence or not of a particular solution that might allow me to override this first difficulty and build a cluster or cloud that can optimize almost any software piece, at least with standard computation (i mean Just using cpu), as gpgpu requires code to be re-written

Comment: perhaps a specific cloud solution

Comment: sorry for my noob questions, but i'm really passionate about these specific fields, but i have a very limited know how on the topics